# How to send the Case attachment in an alert email using VF Email Template?

Tags: email, attachment, vf-email-template

I want to send the `Case attachment` in an email to `Risk & Legal team` when Manager approves the request. For this I have created the `VF Email Template` (Because in Email Template I have header, footer and need to send some details in an tabular format).

I also have the Approval Process for Approved and Reject, when manager approves the request an email alert goes to R&L Team, in that email I need to send the case attachment. I am following this URL: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_email_sending_attachments.htm

Through VF Email Template, how can I send the CaseId to controller or how can I attached the documents with VF Email template which will be going to R&L Team ?

Comment: I don't think so you can send attachment in approval process. https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjPkqf3mtHTAhVJwI8KHXkUCXQQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsuccess.salesforce.com%2FideaView%3Fid%3D08730000000l4D3AAI&usg=AFQjCNE1Wx8It6RdpasVmue7nXxvEctzBQ&sig2=fyrfQgONR8PQ9JHXp1m3xA

Comment: I've included lists of attachments in vf email template with an apex:repeat, but never tried to send the attachments themselves.   Would a list w links suffice?

Comment: No, I would need to compulsory send the Case Attachments (Present in the Notes and Attachment section) in a alert mail to Risk and Legal Team.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a merge field to send a link to the attachment you want to reference per [this example expense approval process](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=approvals_useful_approval_processes_expense.htm&type=0&language=en_US&release=206.19) from the Help. Otherwise, I don't know of a standard means of doing what you ask.

The only alternative means *might* be to write a custom class using methods from the [Approval Namespace](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_namespace_Approval.htm) to insert the approval request while adding the attachment at the same time. This is clearly not standard functionality and still may not process through the system as you'd like. It obviously wouldn't work if you allowed approvals to be made using SF1 in their Chatter Feed.